# Why am I getting one too many tabs in Emacs?

Tags: python, emacs, elisp

init.el

```
(setq make-backup-files nil)

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/")

; Add all top-level subdirectories of .emacs.d to the load path
(progn (cd "~/.emacs.d")
       (normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path))
; Third party libraries are stored in ~/.emacs.d/extern
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/extern")
(progn (cd "~/.emacs.d/extern")
       (normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path))

; Python-specific enchancements
(load-library "python")

; Zenburn color theme
(require 'color-theme-zenburn)

(color-theme-zenburn)
```

python.el

```
; use tabs in files (urgh...yelp!)
;(setq-default indent-tabs-mode t)

; tab display width of 4 columns by default
; (throw everything at the wall, and eventually something will stick...)
;(setq-default tab-width 4)  ; Normal emacs tab-width
; (setq-default c-basic-offset 2) ; python-mode.el setting
;(setq-default py-indent-offset 4) ; Use Tabs, not spaces
;(setq-default py-smart-indentation nil) ; Don't try to guess tab width

(defun customize-py-tabs ()
    (setq tab-width 4
        py-indent-offset 4
        indent-tabs-mode t
        py-smart-indentation nil
   )
)

(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'customize-py-tabs)

; Highlight useless whitespace
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
                  (lambda () (setq show-trailing-whitespace t)))
```

I'm trying to setup my emacs to tab to the right level on my python code, but it adds in extra tab. It's consistant. If there should be 4 tabs, I get 5. Any suggestions?

for example

```py
def func:
        # This is where it puts me
    # This is where it SHOULD put be
```

Comment: It'll all end in tears... mark my words.

Comment: I'm using ^q tab right now. It's a pain. Too much more of this and I'll be forced to use vi. :P

Comment: What is the value of `indent-line-func` in that buffer? (Do `C-h v indent-line-func` while visiting that buffer to find out.) For me it's `python-indent-line` from python.el, and it works well enough. Looking at the implementation, I note that it will cycle through all possible tab positions, so perhaps hitting tab again will indent to the correct location.

Comment: It works correctly for me, both for newline-and-indent (C-j) and indent-region (C-M-\)  For you, does it do the same, incorrect behavior for both?

Comment: Works for me out of the box, I'm wondering which Emacs version you are using, and whether perhaps your file name `python.el` somehow shadows the system definition of `python-mode`?  Can you make it work with `emacs -q` and/or `emacs -Q` for a start?  The variables called py-something are not available in my Emacs, so I suspect you are using a different Python mode than us others, perhaps ...?  What do you get from `M-x locate-library python`?

Comment: In a python file indent-line-func is set to indent-relative. I'm running emacs 23.3.

Comment: C-j does the same thing.

Comment: The py-smart-indentation is defined for me and is nil. Python mode is "/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp/progmodes/python.elc". python-indent-offset is 4, but tab-width is 8 in python files, and 4 by default?!?

Comment: Rename your `python.el` to `python-settings.el` to be safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any Python indentation which starts with setting `tab-width` to something else than 8 is doomed to bring trouble.  `tab-width` determines how Emacs *displays* the TAB character, not *how far* to indent in response to hitting the `tab` key.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't need to solve this problem. [Style Guide for Python Code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) strongly recommends using 4 spaces, why not follow it?

Comment: Not an option. This is for work and style is tab only. We follow PEP8 except for that one spot.